# Excel VBA copy column to another column

Tags: vba, excel

here is the code:

```
Public Sub mysub()
Dim colA As Integer, colB As Integer
Dim rowA As Integer, rowB As Integer
colA = 3
colB = 19
rowA = 7
rowB = 7
lastA = Cells(Rows.Count, colA).End(xlUp).Row
For x = rowA To lastA
    Data = Cells(x, colA)
    Cells(rowB, colB) = Data
    rowB = rowB + 1
Next x

End Sub
```

it work fine but it will keep rewrite the colB, how could I let it paste on another column?
I want to try End(xlLeft).column but couldn't let it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand you're trying to paste the data in the first empty column in a certain row. If so then you can use this code:

```
Public Sub mysub()
Dim colA As Integer, colB As Integer
Dim rowA As Integer, rowB As Integer
colA = 3
rowA = 7
rowB = 7
lastA = Cells(Rows.Count, colA).End(xlUp).Row
For x = rowA To lastA
    Data = Cells(x, colA)

    'check for first empty column in the x row
    colB = Cells(x, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1

    Cells(rowB, colB) = Data
    rowB = rowB + 1
Next x
```

End Sub